# '\n' is not working when creating .txt file in iOS

Tags: objective-c, file, xcode4.5, rtf

In my application,

I have create .txt file programatically. file create successfully. but \n is not working in this file.

I have use following code for this.

```
  NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"line 1 \nline 2 \nline 3"];
  NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",@"REFINESEARCH"]];
  [str writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
```

When I open REFINESEARCH.txt file in mac it will working fine. 
But when I open this file in windows OS. it's looking like this..

\n is not working here. 
how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: What encoding does notepad use?

Comment: try it,Replace \n with <br>.

Comment: <br> is for HTML. Here I am not creating any HTML file.

Comment: It works on a mac with **\n**. Coding UTF-8 with TextEdit.

Comment: I check your code in my application and it's work fine for me. just replace your write method as per my answer. I checked that file in both Mac and windows and it's work fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your method:

```
  [str writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
```

With:

```
 [str writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Windows (or more specifically, Notepad) uses carriage return/line feed to display new lines. Use `\r\n` instead and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Modiifed your code as only (\r) will work so just replace \n to \r and try:-

```
NSString *str=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"line 1 \rline 2 \rline 3"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDesktopDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *pdfPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",@"REFINESEARCH"]];
[str writeToFile:pdfPath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: also \r will work on both windows and macos so if you used only \r it will work